Integral preserved under change of branch cut?
I am computing an integral which involves a fractional power, which uses the branch cut $-\frac{\pi}{4} <\theta <\frac{3\pi}{4}  $. The specifics of the integral aren't important but it looks something like this:
$$\int_Cg(z)z^{a}dz.$$
I want to preserve the integral but change the branch cut to $0<\theta <2\pi$ as seen in the picture in the right. Will the integral be preserved in this case?
My thinking is that it will be because the curve lies between $0<\theta<\frac{3\pi }{4}$.


The integral will not change. Simply because for all $z$ on your contour, $\arg_1(z)=\arg_2(z)$ for the two argument functions you declare so $(z^a)_{\text{version 1}}=(z^a)_{\text{version 2}}$ so you are comparing the integral of two identically equal functions, so now it is immediate that the integrals are the same.
